# C ifdef, else, endif directives

Tags: c

Let us presume that we have the next fragment of code in a C program:

```
#ifdef USE_FORK
  CODE...

#else 
  phtread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread,NULL,clientDispatch,&client);
#endif
```

Can you explain me what are these directives, ifdef, else, endif. What happens when we use C directives?

Comment: These directives are adequately documented in numerous places on the web.  Have you made an effort to read the documentation and understand it?  http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/ifdef.html

Comment: Yes, i read some about these. I don't understand, I am beginner in C programming. I don't understand easy the C programming, I am obliged to learn it to past the exam.

Comment: Read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/),

Preprocessor directives are lines included in the code of programs preceded by a hash sign (#). These lines are not program statements but directives for the preprocessor. The preprocessor examines the code before actual compilation of code begins and resolves all these directives before any code is actually generated by regular statements.

`#ifdef` allows a section of a program to be compiled only if the macro that is specified as the parameter has been defined, no matter which its value is. For example:

```
#ifdef TABLE_SIZE
int table[TABLE_SIZE];
#endif
```

In this case, the line of code `int table[TABLE_SIZE];` is only compiled **if** `TABLE_SIZE` was previously defined with `#define`, independently of its value. If it was not defined, that line will **not be included** in the program compilation.

The `#if`, `#else` and `#elif` (i.e., "else if") directives serve to specify some condition to be met in order for the portion of code they surround to be compiled. The condition that follows `#if` or `#elif` can only **evaluate constant expressions**, including macro expressions. For example:

```
#if TABLE_SIZE > 200
#undef TABLE_SIZE
#define TABLE_SIZE 200

#elif TABLE_SIZE < 50
#undef TABLE_SIZE
#define TABLE_SIZE 50

#else
#undef TABLE_SIZE
#define TABLE_SIZE 100
#endif

int table[TABLE_SIZE];
```

Notice how the entire structure of `#if`, `#elif` and `#else` chained directives ends with `#endif`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.7.html

This link should explain to you the directives. Additionally, with the directives if the condition after #ifdef becomes true then the compiler will compile the following code otherwise it would look for the next directive and compile the following code.

In your example therefore, if USE_FORK is a true expression then the CODE... will be compiled, otherwise, the lines with definition to threads will be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Its a conditional group, a preprocessor command.  If the macro is defined i.e. USE_FORK then the code will executed up to #else, if the macro is not defined then the code at #else will execute up to #endif